# How to adjust the elements responsively for different widths and heights

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, ionic2

Below is the screenshot that contains OK text as an element and 2 other elements in the left & right side and in the last buttons.

```css
.center-text {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: normal;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 25px;
 line-height: 30px;
 letter-spacing: normal;
 opacity: 1.0;
 margin-top: 25% !important;
}
.lower-content {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.group:before, .group:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
}
.group:after {
 clear: both;
}
.group {
 clear: both;
 *zoom: 1;
}
.lower-content-left {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 1.5%;
 width: 63%;
}
.lower-content-right {
 float: right;
 margin: 0 1.5%;
 width: 30%;
}
.button-left {
 position: absolute;
 width: 140px;
 height: 140px;
 left: 100px !important;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 top: 620px;
}
.button-left>div {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}
.notification-button {
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 zoom: 2.0;
}
.button-right {
 position: absolute;
 width: 140px;
 height: 140px;
 left: 250px;
 right: 20px;
 bottom: 0;
 top: 620px;
}
.button-right>div {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}
.heart-button {
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 zoom: 2.0;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-text">Ok</div> 

<div class="group">

<div class="lower-content-left">
  <div class="lower-left">click here</div>
  <div class="search-channels">Click
    <br>Here</div>
</div>

<div class="lower-content-right">
  <div class="lower-right">Otherwise Click here</div>
  <div class="qrCode">Click here
    <br>Also</div>
</div>

<div class="button-left">
  <div>
    <ion-icon name="notification" class="notification-button"></ion-icon>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="button-right">
  <div>
    <ion-icon name="heart" class="heart-button"></ion-icon>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Problem** : When I change the width of the screen the buttons hide away or is not present at the present position and same for all elements.
I have posted in the screenshot.I just need to edit my css to make it responsive according to the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: With the given code, it works fine. Check this fiddle with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/sr77Lo98/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use to css by resolution.

Example:

```
@media (max-width: 300px) {
    .your-class {
        your:option; }
        }

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .your-class {
        your:option; }
        }
```

Comment: I dont want to use media queries